# Is it possible to control the double tap gesture of a photo view widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, carousel, pinchzoom

I am using a carousal slider to display multiple images like in a social media feed.
I implemented zoom using photo view, which works fine but it also zooms the image on double tap which I don't want.

Is there a way to overwrite the double tap of Photo view, to implement a custom functionality?

https://pub.dev/packages/photo_view

Also, tried alternatives like interactive viewer and gesture detector to zoom images but they didn't work with carousel slider.

Comment: Have you tried Interactive Viewer inside PageView as chilren

Comment: @NaveenAvidi Thanks a lot! trying it out, it does look good.

Comment: Make sure that panEnabled : false in Interactive Viewer, else it won't slide to other image (or widget). happy coding... !

Answer (score 0):

There are other options as well. But I will answer this with your exact regard, i.e. the `photo_view` package.

There's no direct option/param to stop the double tap action. Instead, you can tweak a little internal parameter (either by creating a fork or editing the source locally if you prefer).

As per this [comment](https://github.com/bluefireteam/photo_view/issues/388#issuecomment-771496001):

```dart
 return PhotoViewGestureDetector(
    child: child,
    onDoubleTap: nextScaleState, ///Remove or comment this line.
    onScaleStart: onScaleStart,
    onScaleUpdate: onScaleUpdate,
    onScaleEnd: onScaleEnd,
    hitDetector: this,
    onTapUp: widget.onTapUp == null ? null : onTapUp,
    onTapDown: widget.onTapDown == null ? null : onTapDown,
 );
```

Update this in the `photo_view_core.dart` file.